# Using pyproject.toml to define inspection rules of PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, lint, flake8, pyproject.toml

I use PyCharm and have a `pyproject.toml`, currently configured for `flake8`.

Can I make PyCharm use the ignore list for its own inspections too?

My `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.flake8]
ignore = [
   "I101",  # Imported names are in the wrong order
   "I201",  # Missing newline between import groups
]
```

I am *not* looking for a suggestion to configure `flake8` as external tool in PyCharm, I am looking to alter/configure the live inspection of PyCharm, as shown e.g. its Problems tab.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I make PyCharm use the ignore list for its own inspections too?

The way JetBrains offers to integrate 3rd party tool inspection functionalities into PyCharm is by using their [Qodana](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html#inspect_code_with_qodana) tool.

This is still separate from the PyCharm linter per se. PyCharm's linter integrates PEP8, with some Flake8 checks and other niceties like spellchecking and refactoring suggestions but it's never been a complete substitute for popular 3rd party code-quality tools (like mypy, Flake8 or python-black) and PyCharm keeps it's own [configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-and-ide-settings.html#location_of_directories) that are proprietary and not meant to be compatible with `pyproject.toml` settings.

At the time of this writing you shouldn't expect complete integration of 3rd party tools with the native PyCharm linter warning system and instead consider the PyCharm linter as its own separate tool geared towards giving you some limited assistance while writing the code.

There have been very few attempts at publishing Flake8 integration plugins for PyCharm, there are for example [Flake8 support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11563-flake8-support) and [flake8-for-pycharm](https://gitlab.com/ramast/flake8-for-pycharm) but these plugins seem to have been limited and abandoned in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [PyCharm's native inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html) and [`flake8` inspections](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/violations.html) are different, and PyCharm does not natively support importing `flake8` configurations directly into its own inspection settings.

As a workaround, you can try and manually configure PyCharm's inspections to mirror the ignore list in `pyproject.toml`. Go to `File > Settings > Editor > Inspections` in PyCharm, and adjust the inspection settings to reflect the rules you want to ignore, as specified in your `pyproject.toml`.

Since PyCharm's inspections are not directly compatible with `flake8`, some rules might not have a one-to-one correspondence, and this process might involve some approximation.

If you often change your `flake8` settings and want a more automated way to keep PyCharm in sync, consider writing a custom script or a PyCharm plugin that reads your `pyproject.toml` and adjusts PyCharm's inspection settings accordingly.

Comment: flake8 and its any plugins have rules that are much much more diverse than what PyCharm's built-in inspections could ever offer.

Comment: @bugmenot123 True, that is what I have found in my tests.

Comment: @bugmenot123  If you haven't already, integrating flake8 as an external tool in PyCharm, although not ideal, allows you to run flake8 checks alongside your regular development workflow.

Comment: Thanks! As I said in my post, that is not what I am looking for. Live, realtime inspection is what I am really after.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I know. My answer represents what I have found so far, meaning not what you are looking for.