# Getting Unresolved attribute reference for inherited methods in Pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm, python-poetry

I am getting **Unresolved attribute reference for inherited methods** in my Pycharm Django project.

What I have tried without any luck:

- Used interpreter through poetry (also tried venv through poetry)
- Also tried to Invalidate caches and restart.

Note: This issue seems to occurred only on inherited methods. When importing classes directly the autocomplete suggestions propagate correctly.

[image]

Comment: This is simply the linter that can not understand the large amount of meta-programming by Django.

Comment: It is however not entirely clear what you mean with "inherited methods"?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem I mean that if my model has an attribute, within the class it will show. But whatever i call from the inherited class `from django.db import models` will not work. e.g. `myModel.objects.all()` objects is unresolved.

Comment: Please edit the question to also include the source code as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). For PyCharm linter bugs a question should also say what your exact PyCharm version is.

Comment: Consider reporting this bug on the [JetBrains Python bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: @bad_coder created: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-65610/Getting-Unresolved-attribute-reference-for-inherited-methods-in-Pycharm

Comment: @csandreas1 nice :) **PY-65610**, just the bug's high serial number is mind boggling :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* an error. This is simply the linter that can not understand the large amount of meta-programming by Django. Django's models has a lot of magic going on. For example if you define a field `foo = models.IntegerField()`, then `self.foo` is *not* the `IntegerField`, but the `int` for that record.

This meta-programming could probably be understood by a smart linter, but it would take a lot of analysis.

The PyCharm professional edition has a linter that contains some reasoning w.r.t. Django's metaprogramming, although (likely) a lot is hardcoded. There are also tools like pylint-django` that have some understanding of Django.

But there is thus no error, it is just the *linter* that is confused.

Comment: probably hardcoded but it's called PyCharm professional :D

Comment: @csandreas1 there have been several posts about PyCharm's linter, [I wrote one some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77594548) it's advisable to rely on 3rd party linting/type checking tools when they're available.

Comment: @bad_coder thanks, I already use some linters via pre-commit hooks, such as flake8, mypi, isort but my question was more related to the IDE auto-generation stubs and the warning I got.